# Python - Key detection with simple modules

Tags: python, text, editor, esp8266, micropython

I'm trying to make a text editor for MicroPython. This 'nano'-like(or vim) text editor should be able to run *on* the device, 
what I'm not looking for is modules that would not run on the **ESP8266**.

What I'm using at the moment is simple modules such as '*sys*' and '*os*'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Added some content of the links to improve the answer**

Extract of libs that MicroPython have

**Builtin Functions**

`cmath` – mathematical functions for complex numbers

`gc` – control the garbage collector

`math` – mathematical functions

`select` – wait for events on a set of streams

`sys` – system specific functions

`ubinascii` – binary/ASCII conversions

`ucollections` – collection and container types

`uhashlib` – hashing algorithm

`uheapq` – heap queue algorithm

`uio` – input/output streams

`ujso`n – JSON encoding and decoding

`uos` – basic “operating system” services

`ure` – regular expressions

`usocket` – socket module

`ustruct` – pack and unpack primitive data types

`utime` – time related functions

`uzlib` – zlib decompression

**MicroPython-specific libraries**

Functionality specific to the MicroPython implementation is available in the following libraries.

`machine` — functions related to the board

`micropython` – access and control MicroPython internals

`network` — network configuration

`uctypes` – access binary data in a structured way

**More info in:**

[MicroPython libs](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.8.2/pyboard/library/index.html), if you find it here you'll be able to use it.

[MicroPython for ESP8266](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html)

[MicroPython docs](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.8.2/pyboard/index.html)